# Xml file not received properlly

Tags: java, android, http-post

I am using this code in order to get the rss file from the given url:

```
// get the xml file from the given url in a string format
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) 
{
    String xml = null;
    try 
    {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

This is the code for getting the xml file text:

```
    String yahoo_url = "http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=intc&region=US&lang=en-US";
    parser = new XMLParser();
    String text = parser.getXmlFromUrl(yahoo_url);
    System.out.println(text);
```

Instead of giving me the entire file, I only get two lines:

```
"?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
rss version="2.0"><channel/></rss?"
```

What may be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: by the way, you need to consume entity if ClientProtocolException is thrown, you can do it by `EntityUtils.consumes(entity)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be some encoding issue. If your XML string is processed using the wrong charset, it could be that some characters are misinterpreted as e.g. new lines (would explain the line break in your sample) or End-Of-File.

Try telling `EntityUtils` the charset of the string (probably UTF-8):

```
xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Could you provide the outputs of `Charset.defaultCharset();`, `ContentType.get(httpEntity)` and `ContentType.getOrDefault(httpEntity)`?